# how to make a Custom CheckButton on TileContainer checked false DevExpress

Tags: winforms, microsoft-metro, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a CheckButton on TileContainer.
I showed a PopUp Menu on Checked Event of CheckButton.
Now, I need to Uncheck that CheckButton at the end of the event.

```
this.tileContainer1.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonPanel.IBaseButton[] {
        new DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.WindowsUIButton("ShowList", global::DMS.Properties.Resources.speech_bubble, -1, DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.ButtonStyle.CheckButton, 0)});
```

Comment: Please provide a code for buttons initialization...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario correctly, you can use the following approch:

```
WindowsUIButton checkButton = new WindowsUIButton()
{
    Caption = "Check Button",
    Style = ButtonStyle.CheckButton
};
checkButton.CheckedChanged += checkButton_CheckedChanged;
tileContainer1.Buttons.Add(checkButton);
//...
int reentranceCount = 0;
void checkButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(reentranceCount > 0) return;
    /*do some stuff */
    Uncheck((WindowsUIButton)sender);
}
void Uncheck(WindowsUIButton button) {
    reentranceCount++;
    try {
        button.Checked = false;
    }
    finally { reentranceCount--; }
}
```

**Update:**
If  you are using the [TileContiner.ButtonChecked](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsWindowsUIBaseContentContainer_ButtonCheckedtopic) event you should update the code above as follows:

```
//...
tileContainer1.ButtonChecked += tileContainer_ButtonChecked;
//...
void tileContainer_ButtonChecked(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e) {
    if(reentranceCount > 0) return;
    /*do some stuff */
    Uncheck((WindowsUIButton)e.Button);
}
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.TileContainer' to type 'DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.WindowsUIButton'.